# Unpacking a shared EditText to use in another activity

Tags: android, get, android-edittext, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to pass an EditText value to an Alarm receiver Activity, what the EditText does is put a number pertaining to the amount of that particular alarm. When the alarm is answered the EditText should `int--`, I have everything else working but I can not figure out how to package up the process of:

```
amountt++;
amountText = Integer.toString(amountt);
amountedit.setHint(amountText);
amnt.setText(amountText);



editor.putString("numbers", amountText);
editor.commit();
```

From the set alarm activity to the Receiver activity:

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             mPlayer.stop();
             amountedit.setHint(amountText);
             amnt.setText("value"+ amountt--);

                finish();
                stoplaydialog.dismiss();
return;
```

I've tried a few things so far such as:

```
  carry = new Intent();
  carry.putExtra("numbers", amountt);
  startActivity(carry);
```

To :

```
  String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("amount");
```

But I can't figure out how to "unpack" it and put it into the context of

`amnt.setText("value"+ amountt--);`

I'm very new to this, a little holliday hobby so I appologise if this is a stupid question. Thanks.

EDIT:
Launching from this now..

```
Intent intent=new Intent(CaAdd.this,AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("numbers", amountt);

    PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(CaAdd.this, 2,    `intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);`
   AlarmManager alm=(AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
```

But I'm getting a `int:null` error on the AlarmReceiver activity.

Comment: try to put full source code

Comment: Are you stuck at parsing String into int? `int amount = Inetegr.parseInt(value)` should work. Then you can `++` or `--` it.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the quick replies, I've just tried  M-WaJeEh answer and I'm getting the error`The final local variable amountt cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type`?

Comment: Nevermind I just declared `int amountt` global gonna run it now

Comment: So the problem I'm having now is that I have no "activity" to start the intent, because it starts once the alarm has been called not OnClick etc. I'm guessing I need to do some sort of pendingIntent thing?

Comment: I'm getting this when trying to Launch
`java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"`

Comment: That is just because you have set the value of the int variable ="null"

Comment: @Andru nah, it was throwing me a null because I had an int where it expected a string.

Comment: Have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You have call wrong intent. It should be:

```
String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("numbers");
```

instead of:

```
String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("amount");
```